# QtConcurrent error: reference to non-static member

Tags: c++, qt, non-static, qtconcurrent

I am running Qt 5.1 and QtQuick 2.0 on a Mac with OS-X 10.8.4.

My Qt-QML GUI becomes unresponsive because I am blocking the event loop with file I/O operations.  The usual approach to solving it is to use multiple threads as discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448852/qt-progress-bar-does-not-progress-incrementally-it-jumps) by Will Bickford.

To do so, I am attempting to use:

```
QtConcurrent::blockingMapped()
```

which can be simpler than using an explicit QFuture object.  I have been reading the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentmap.html) and [cool examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/examples-threadandconcurrent.html) and got the following code working (modeled after this [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtconcurrent/map.html)):

```
// NOTE: this all seems to work:
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>
#include "dataobject.h"
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentMap>

DataObject load(const QString &file) {
    std::cout << "File I/O in thread = " << QThread::currentThread() << std::endl;
    return DataObject anObject(file);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...

    // Create a list of filenames:
    int count = 5;
    QList<QString> allFiles;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        allFiles.append(QString("aFileName"));
    }
    std::cout << "# of files = " << allFiles.size() << std::endl;

    QList<DataObject> allTheDataObjects = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(allFiles,load);
    std::cout << "# of objects = " << allTheDataObjects.size() << std::endl;

    ...
}
```

and here are the header and implementation files for DataObject:

```
#include <QString>
class DataObject
{
public:
    DataObject();
    DataObject(QString filename);
    QString theFileName;
};
```

---

```
#include "dataobject.h"

DataObject::DataObject() {
    theFileName = QString("no file");
}
DataObject::DataObject(QString filename) {
    theFileName = filename;
    //...
    // Do file I/O stuff (slow) ...
}
```

This is not very realistic but serves as a simple sketch to illustrate the problem I encountered below.

The problem occurs when I try to encapsulate QtConcurrent::blockingMapped() within an additional "datamodel.h" class:

```
#include "dataobject.h"
class DataModel
{
public:
    DataModel();
    void runConcurrent();
    DataObject load(const QString& fileList);
};
```

---

```
#include "datamodel.h"
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentMap>
#include <iostream>

DataModel::DataModel() {}
DataObject DataModel::load(const QString &file) {
    std::cout << "File I/O in thread = " << QThread::currentThread() << std::endl;
    return DataObject anObject(file);
}
void DataModel::runConcurrent() {
    // Create a list of filenames:
    int count = 5;
    QList<QString> allFiles;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        allFiles.append(QString("dummyFileName"));
    QList<DataObject> allTheDataObjects = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(allFiles, this->load);
    std::cout << "# of objects = " << allTheDataObjects.size() << std::endl;
}
```

And then main() becomes (note that I also moved the load() method into the DataModel class):

```
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>
#include "dataobject.h"
#include "datamodel.h"
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentMap>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...

    DataModel theModel;
    theModel.runConcurrent();

    ...
}
```

But now there is a compiler error:

```
datamodel.cpp: error: reference to non-static member function must be called:
QList<DataObject> allTheDataObjects = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(allFiles, this->load);
```

I was not able to fix the compiler error by initializing a DataObject or DataModel instance (so that a non-static member function could be visible) and wasn't sure what else to try.

Next I suspected this could be due to a problem with "functor" bindings when setting up the QtConcurrent arguments (I don't have boost installed so am not using [boost::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function)) so I tried [Mat's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361044/qtconcurrentmap-with-member-function-can-not-compile) of using C++ 11 lambdas by replacing:

```
this->load
```

with:

```
[this](const QString& file){load(file);}
```

giving the code:

```
QList<DataObject> allTheDataObjects = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(allFiles, 
                                       [this](const QString& file){load(file);});
```

Now I no longer get the non-static member error, but a new error occurs (pointing at the above line):

```
datamodel.cpp: error: expected expression:
```

I've really gotten down a rabbit hole on this one, its probably a simple mistake but I am having trouble sorting it out.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it to work.

In case this can benefit those who may not want to mess with bindings or write their own "functor" (the approach below is way simpler):

Start by using the static type in datamodel.h file for the "load" function:

```
static DataObject load(const QString& fileList);
```

This works because static functions of a C++ class can be called without the need for instantiating the object.

Then, in the datamodel.cpp file, it is this simple:

```
DataModel::load
```

to give:

```
QList<DataObject> allTheDataObjects = 
                      QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(allFiles, DataModel::load);
```

Then the code runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't use C++11 which has lambda expressions. So use binds from STL or Boost or create function object.

```
QList<DataObject> allTheDataObjects = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(allFiles, 
                                   std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&DataModel::load), this));
```

Ok above solution cant work with references (know bug). Define functor (or use Boost::bind):

```
class LoadDataModel /*: public std::unary_function<QString, DataObject>*/ {
public:
    LoadDataModel(DataModel *p) : d(p) {}

    DataObject operator()(const QString &s) const {
        return d->load(s);
    }
private:
    DataModel *d;
}

QList<DataObject> allTheDataObjects = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(allFiles, LoadDataModel(this));
```

Comment: Did you get your suggestion to work?  After adding the #include <functional>, I tried your code above but now get a bunch of other non-descript errors, e.g., stl_function.h:411: error: multiple overloads of 'operator()' ... and so on, for many lines.  Any further ideas?  All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I forgot that there is a problem with references: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7823004/1387438 , so in this case the fastest way to fix the problem is define functor.

Comment: I'll work on defining the functor but are we even sure that the functor is the issue?  Note that "load" is already a unary function, so there are no other arguments that we need to bind to. Note also that this code runs fine (as illustrated above) until QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(), is packaged into the DataModel class, so essentially, if functor bindings were the issue, why didn't it break without the DataModel class?

Comment: No load is NOT unary function. To invoke it you always need two arguments: `this` written before function name and `fileList` written after function name. You can't invoke this function without the object.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, but it still seems strange that it runs fine without the DataModel class.